# Lentidão resposta API PHP

Tags: php, mvc, api

estou fazendo um projeto com perfis de bandas. Estou tentando usar a API do last.fm.

Para base de teste eu baixei a API PHP: https://github.com/fxb/php-last.fm-api

As classes eu deixei em Root/src/classes.php, e comecei a usar o Artist::search($artistName,$limit);

Só que eu quero exibir apenas as bandas cadastradas no banco. O Script funciona de fato, mas a **resposta do site demora 7 segundos para retorna**. Não sou nenhum "expert",então se alguém tiver uma ideia de como otimizar esse script.

```
            <div class="grid-cont">
            <div class="banda_search">
                <!-- hot news -->

                <form action="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquise pelo nome da banda que você procura!">

                    </form>
                        </div>

                <?php

                    $getPage = (!empty($Link->getLocal()[1]) ? $Link->getLocal()[1] : 0);
                    $Pager = new Pager(HOME . '/bandas/');
                    $Pager->ExePager($getPage, 12);

                    $readbanda = new Read;
                    $readbanda->ExeRead("ws_bands", "WHERE band_parent IS NOT NULL ORDER BY band_date DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset", "limit={$Pager->getLimit()}&offset={$Pager->getOffset()}");


                      if (!$readbanda->getResult()):
                          $Pager->ReturnPage();
                          WSErro("Desculpe, não existem bandas cadastradas no momento, favor volte mais tarde!", WS_INFOR);
                      else:

                            echo'<div class="banda_news">';
                            echo'<div class="grid-row">';
                            foreach ($readbanda->getResult() as $banda):
                            extract($banda);

                               $results = Artist::search($band_title,"1");

                                   foreach($results as $artist):



                                        echo'   <div class="grid-col grid-col-3">
                                        <a href="'.HOME.'/banda/'.$band_name.'" class="small" alt="'.$band_title.'" title="'.$band_title.'">
                                        <span class="pic" alt="'.$band_title.'" title="'.$band_title.'" style="background-image: url(' . $artist->getImage(4) . ')"></span>

                                        <h3>'.$band_title.'</h3>
                                        </a>
                                        </div>';




                                  endforeach;
                            endforeach;

                            echo '</div>
                                  </div>';
                      endif;
                    $Pager->ExePaginator("ws_bands", "ORDER BY band_date");
                    echo $Pager->getPaginator();?>


                </div>
```

Se alguém tiver uma **ideia melhor de pegar as imagens dos artistas pela API** e que seja mais rápido,agradeço.

Comment: (eu não entendo desta classe então me perdoe se estou falando besteira) Para cada loop que acessa o `Artist::search($band_title, "1")` é feito uma requisição ao servidor `http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/`, se a conexão fosse persistente (eu acho que não é) talvez não demorasse tanto. Ou talvez você deveria chamar de outra maneira, mas infelizmente não tenho conhecimento necessário  sobre esta classe.

Answer (score 1):

Para otimizar a aplicação agrupe todas os nomes de bandas em uma string e utilize a query "IN" na condicional WHERE da consulta do seu banco. Isso fará com que você faça apenas 1 consulta no banco, evitando alguns segundos de espera entre solicitação e resposta.

Construa os valores do conjunto para o IN():

```
$bands = $readbanda->getResult();
$bands_sql = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($bands); $i++){
    $bands_sql .= '\''.$bands[$i]['band_title'].'\'';
    if($i+1<count($bands)){
    $bands_sql.= ',';
    }
}
```

Esse pedaço de código deve gerar uma string com o nome de todas as bandas, agora você deve criar uma função para consultar seu banco, deve ser algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM bands WHERE band_title IN ($bands_sql);
```

O retorno dessa query deve ser exatamente o que está sendo feito hoje, mas com otimizações de tempo. Espero ter ajudado.